# How can I change the color of certain lines in chartjs / vue-chartjs?

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I notice that a default bar chart always has a darker zero line.  I also notice the horizontal line at -1.0 is also darker. I want those colors to be the same as the grid.  How do I do that?

A bare-bones example is shown here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lnv3cmz0/1/

```
Vue.component('chart', {
    template:`
    <canvas></canvas>
  `,
  props:['type'],
  mounted(){
    this._chart = new Chart(this.$el, {
        type:this.type,
      data:[],
    })
  },
})

//App setup
new Vue({
    el:'#vue',
})
```

Update:

The zeroLine option no longer seems to be available. I am using the latest/greatest Chart (v4.2.0) and no longer have this issue.  Below is a sample of what I'm doing

```
  const ctx = document.getElementById('chart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  chart.value = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      datasets: [],
    },
    options: {
      onClick: (evt) => handleOnClick(evt),
      interaction: {
        mode: 'nearest',
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          labels: {
            generateLabels(chart) { // other code here }}
          }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'My Super cool Chart',
        },
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          grid: {
            color: () => myBackgroundColor,
          },
          beginAtZero: false,
          ticks: {
            callback: (value) => doSomethingOnCallaback(value),
            // fontColor: myBackgroundColor,
          },
          type: 'linear',
        },
        y: {
          grid: {
            color: () => myBackgroundColor,
          },
          max: myStart,
          min: myEnd,
          beginAtZero: false,
          ticks: {
            callback: (value) => `Tick ${value}`,
            stepSize: 15.0,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is zeroLineColor in the GridLines
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration

Comment: Could you show some code on how you solved this?

Comment: @FelixD.I updated the original post to include an update. Hope it helps